# Привязка DNS имени к бесплатному хостингу приложений OpenShift

Tags: dns, openshift

Суть вопроса заключается в том что я являюсь владельцем некого DNS имени (с целью дальнейших вопросов по существу раскрою его legan.by) зарегистрированного на hoster.by, есть желание привязать его суб домен 2го уровня к примеру openshift.legan.by к длинному и не удобному в повседневном использовании имени на бесплатном хостинге приложений OpenShift (а именно http://openshiftwebap-openshiftwebap.7e14.starter-us-west-2.openshiftapps.com/OpenShiftWebAPTest/)

что бы получилось вот так http://openshift.legan.by/OpenShiftWebAPTest/

и когда я в настройках DNS выставляю CNAME запись openshift.legan.by для openshiftwebap-openshiftwebap.7e14.starter-us-west-2.openshiftapps.com. (точку ставлю в конце)
то ни чего не выходит, не происходит перенаправления на мою страницу (а точнее я попадаю куда-то не туда :) на IP некого другого проекта OpenShift который естественно не содержит моего контекста) (причём некоторое время IP адреса при попытке трасировки длинного и короткого адреса совпадают) , что я делаю не так :(

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо на стороне веб-сервера прописать алиас для вашего сайта.
Например, для Апача это будет директива ServerAlias:

```
ServerAlias openshift.legan.by
```

Для nginx:

```
server_name openshift.legan.by
```